# jQuery dialog goes offscreen when using .scrollto plugin (with jsfiddle reproduction)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, scrollto

I need to show a dialog after the window has scrolled to a specific element.  Currently, the dialog opens on top of the page and then the window moves to the intended element.  This means the dialog is now hidden on top of the page.

Here is the problem reproduced in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5ftM/

Is there a way I could show the dialog where the current scroll position?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/t5ftM/1/

```
$.scrollTo("#scroll_here", 500, {
    offset: -200,
    onAfter: function() {
        $("#dialog1").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            title: 'Create',
            buttons: {
                "Save": function() {
                    $('#form').submit();
                },
            },
            modal: true,
            minWidth: 300,
            minHeight: 100
        });
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the page to scroll...

This line :

```
$.scrollTo("#scroll_here", 500, {offset:-200});
```

Automatically scrolls the page to the `#scroll_here` div. And the dialog pops up ad Document Ready as well. If you don't want the page to scroll on load, you need to wrap one of the functions so it occurs as a callback. This will allow one processes to finish, then display the second.